# Can a cream cheese cake be left out and for how long?

Tags: food-safety

I have an awesome cream cheese and blueberry pound cake recipe that I love to bake. Can it be left on the counter and for how long?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a true pound cake, it should be good at room temperature for 2-3 days, well wrapped.

---

The title of your question made it sound like you have a cheese cake, perhaps with a pound cake base.  If that is the case:

Cheesecake is essentially a custard of cream cheese, eggs, and dairy.

None of these foods should normally be left at room temperature for an extended period of time, as they are all quite perishable.

I would recommend leaving a cheesecake out for no more than 2 hours or so, the same as any other perishable food.

See also:  [How do I know if food left at room temperature is still safe to eat?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/34670/how-do-i-know-if-food-left-at-room-temperature-is-still-safe-to-eat)

Comment: It's a cream cheese *pound cake* (http://www.marthastewart.com/315556/cream-cheese-pound-cakes), not a cheesecake.

Comment: A lot of cheesecakes have pound cake cases...  but will update.

Answer (score 0):

Pound cake is good for a day or two on the counter, a week or so in the fridge, and indefinitely in the freezer...they freeze really well due to their high density. The addition of cream cheese doesn't make a notable difference in texture, though if you're using a frosting that will change things.

I tend to make mine in job lots, and freeze them...Stick 'em in a freezer bag, press out the air, and you're good to go. Best to eat it inside a couple of months, or it'll dry out a bit.